# Modelling solenoid with LTSpice

Tags: switches, ltspice, solenoid

Does anyone can give me a hint on how to modelling a solenoid (solenoid locker) with LTspice ?
Here is the characteristics from the supplier (https://www.lextronic.fr/mini-serrure-solenoide-12-v-58746.html) :

```
Power Supply: 12 Vcc
Consumption: 0,42 A
Power: 5 W
Type Pull
Course: 4,4 mm
Durée d'activation max: 120 s
Max Strength. 70 g
Dimensions: 33/28,6 x 28 x 19 mm
```

I tried to find equivalent model of solenoid but not match with the information provided in the datasheet

Comment: How much inductance does it have? How does that inductance change with actuation position? How much detail do you want your model to embody?

Comment: You can already determinate the resistance of the inductor which is 12/0.42= ~28.6 Ohm ...

Answer (score 1):

Your spec sheet of the solenoid offer only a possibility to present the device as a resistor. The calculation is already shown in a given comment. To stay in the truth you can also insert a detection circuit which turns an overtemperature flag ON when the solenoid has been powered continuously 120 seconds, but that's not circuit analysis.

If you happen to want a proper model for induction and what the movement of the armature exactly causes in the drive circuit you should know much more. The device is a kind of electric motor. It has moving mass, mechanical dimensions, some tensioning spring, friction, motion limiters, magnetic properties, wire resistance, changing inductance due the armature motion and maybe some eddy currents due the induction. The actual modelling  of the effect in the drive circuit is complex, because all mentioned things affect, the mechanical happenings cannot be separated from the circuit model.

here's a scientific paper of an attempt to simulate a solenoid:

[https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327490239_Modelling_a_Solenoid's_Valve_Movement](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327490239_Modelling_a_Solenoid%27s_Valve_Movement)

I guess your best option is to get a solenoid and measure what actually happens in the drive circuit. Then you can decide which kind of drive circuit is needed. Very likely there's at least a good reason to kill or recycle the inductive kickback. That's a common practice with relays. With them modelling the relay as a resistor and inductor in series is generally enough. Some tests are needed with varying environment conditions, tear&wear and dirt, too to see is there enough current and force to the wanted operation.

Comment: Thank you, finally I will use my prototype with monitoring the current, the temperature and adjust the component based on the operating ranges. It would be more efficient